# How to displayed title and associated tags followed by each image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one requirement for jsonp, once we enter a tag name in text box, images is displayed, its fine.But after image, title and associated tags will be displayed(each image followed by title and tags).Here is my code. Tags are animal,bird,paris,cow...

```
$('#idSubmit').click(function(){  
  //$('#image-container').html(""); 
   $('img').remove();
   var txtVal = $('#idText').val(); 
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags="+txtVal,
            data:"&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
            success:function(data) {            
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {                                  
                    var tagImgs = $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");                                
                    var tagNames = item.tags;
                    var tagNames = tagNames.split(' ');                 
                    if (tagImgs){
                        $("<div/>").html(tagImgs).appendTo("body").attr('title',tagNames[0]).click(function(){
                          $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                        });         
                        if (i == 9) return false;
                    }                   
                });
            },
            dataType:'jsonp'                    
       });
  });
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALbnC/6/)

Can any one help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want ?

```
$('#idSubmit').click(function(){  
  $('#image-container').html("");  
   var txtVal = $('#idText').val(); 
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags="+txtVal,
            data:"&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
            success:function(data) {

                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {      
                    if (item.media.m){
                        var blockItem = $("<div/>");

                        var blockImgs = $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo( blockItem);
                        var blockTitle = $("<h3/>").html(item.title).appendTo( blockItem)
                        var blockTags = $("<p/>").html(item.tags).appendTo( blockItem)
                        $("#image-container").append( blockItem);

                        if (i == 9) return false;
                    }                   
                });
            },
            dataType:'jsonp'
       });
  });
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALbnC/7/)